# How to change file metadata before download angular2

Tags: angular

I have the downloadUrl of a file. 
What I would want to do is:

1. Button click, I change the metadata of the audio file (song title, composers).
2. Then download the file.
   In the component class:

   `download(){
            const fileUrl = "audios/73n344hd.mp3";
            // Change File metadata
            // Download file
           }`

Here is my download button:

`<button md-button (click)="download()"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</button>`

How can I achieve this?